# Variadic template parameter order problem

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++03, template-argument-deduction

I have a templated function wrapper that I am attempting to update to C++11 syntax (variadic paremeters).

My issue is that I am caught in a "catch 22" where '`Args...`' must be the last template parameter, but at the same time, cannot be defined after the function pointer template parameter.

Any idea if this can actually be solved?

```
  template <typename... Args, void(*Function)(Args...)>
  class function
  {
  public:

    void operator ()(Args... args) const
    {
      (*Function)(std::forward<Args...>(args...));
    }
  };
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using `std::function`?

Comment: Also, can you use C++17?

Comment: My function wrapper uses inheritance and virtual functions.

Comment: Not all users of my library can use C++11 or above.

Comment: I've added the C++11 tag so people will know it is limited to that.

Comment: If you want to use variadic templates and parameters pack you can't limit to `C++03`, It has to be at least `C++11`.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am introducing C++11 compile time options for those that have compilers that support it. The C++03 version of 'function' limits the number of parameters to zero or one. I'm adding the option for N parameters for those whose compilers support C++11. If you are coding to MISRA then the current rules do not support anything later than C++03.

Comment: I've looked at std::function and it doesn't appear to the same as what I require from my version.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to use the template specialization

```
template <typename>
struct myFunc;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct myFunc<R(*)(Args...)>
 {
   // ...
 };
```

but, this way, you intercept (as template parameter) the **type** of the function pointer, not the function pointer itself; so you have to pass the function pointer in some way (constructor?).

Also observe that, if you want to use perfect forwarding, you have to transform `operator()` in a template method receiving arguments as universal references (`&&`).

Something as follows

```
   template <typename ... As>
   R operator() (As && ... args) const
    {
      return fun(std::forward<As>(args)...);
    }
```

where `fun` is a pointer of type `R(*)(Args...)`.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int foo (int, long)
 { return 42; }

template <typename>
struct myFunc;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct myFunc<R(*)(Args...)>
 {
   using  funPnt = R(*)(Args...);

   funPnt  fun = nullptr;

   myFunc (funPnt f0) : fun{f0}
    { }

   template <typename ... As>
   R operator() (As && ... args) const
    {
      return fun(std::forward<As>(args)...);
    }
 };

int main ()
 { 
   myFunc<decltype(&foo)>  mf0{&foo};

   std::cout << mf0(1, 2l) << std::endl;
 }
```

If you really want the pointer function as template parameter (but, this way, every function determine a different type; this can be a good or a bad thing according to your needs), you can write the `myFunc` struct receiving before a type (the same pointer type) and then a value of that type.

So

```
template <typename T, T>
struct myFunc;

template <typename R, typename ... Args, R(*Func)(Args...)>
struct myFunc<R(*)(Args...), Func>
 {
   template <typename ... As>
   R operator() (As && ... args) const
    {
      return Func(std::forward<As>(args)...);
    }
 };
```

that can be declared

```
 myFunc<decltype(&foo), foo>  mf0;
```

If you can use C++17, you can simplify using `auto` for type of template values; so you can avoid the type

```
template <auto>
struct myFunc;

template <typename R, typename ... Args, R(*Func)(Args...)>
struct myFunc<Func>
 {
   template <typename ... As>
   R operator() (As && ... args) const
    {
      return Func(std::forward<As>(args)...);
    }
 };
```

and you can create a `myFunc` object as follows

```
myFunc<&foo> mf0;
```

Addendum: if you can use C++17, you can define a deduction guide for the first example (pointer as member, not as template value parameter)

```
template <typename R, typename ... Args>
myFunc (R(*)(Args...))  -> myFunc<R(*)(Args...)>;
```

so, instead of

```
myFunc<decltype(&foo)>  mf0{&foo};
```

you can simply write

```
myFunc  mf0{&foo};
```

Off Topic: I hope that you know that you're reinventing the wheel. As suggested by NathanOliver, the standard provide `std::function`.

Comment: It seems OP wants `template <typename F, F f>
struct myFunc;` or C++17 `template <auto f>
struct myFunc;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - yes... I've added the `auto` C++17 version... maybe I can add a pre-C++17 example...

Comment: @Jarod42 - ok: now I propose both solutions... but maybe is confusing :(

Comment: @max66
This is for an open source template library that must support C++03 where ever possible for embedded applications.
The purpose of the function pointer as a template parameter is to allow maximum efficiency for interrupt callbacks.